# Model event's are not firing

Tags: php, laravel-4

I have the following code in my Post model. The `created` event is fired, but the `updated` is not.

I'm updating the model like this:

```
Post::where('key','=','some_key_goes_here')->first()->fill(['status' => 'approved'])->save();
```

And my model looks like this:

```
public function Post extends \Eloquent {
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        Post::created(function ($model) {
            Queue::push('\MyApp\Jobs\Notifications\sendNotification', [
                'id' => $model->user_id,
                'key' => $model->key,
                'status' => $model->status
            ]);
        });

        Post::updated(function ($model) {
            //if the status has changed
            $statusChanged = false;
            foreach ($model->getDirty() as $attribute => $value) {
                if ($attribute == 'status' && $model->getOriginal($attribute) != $value) {
                    $statusChanged = true;
                }
            }

            if ($statusChanged) {
                Notification::add($model->key, $model->status);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: How do you listing event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Little shorter version of the updated + getOriginal second param as a possible fix.

```
Post::updated(function ($model) {
    //if the status has changed
    foreach ($model->getDirty() as $attribute => $value) {
        if ($attribute == 'status' && $model->getOriginal($attribute, $value) != $value) {
            Notification::add($model->key, $model->status);
            break;
        }
    }
});
```